# The summation $\sum_{k=0}^{2n} (-1)^k \frac{{4n \choose 2k}}{{2n \choose k}}=\frac{1}{1-2n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, definite-integrals, summation, binomial-coefficients

This summation has been created by perseverance over a long period of time by using the results from the Table of Series and Integrals By I.S. Gradshteyn and I.M.  Rhyzik [GR].

The  idea was to make a summation of binomial coefficients by utilizing the Integral representation of the reciprocal of the Beta (Integral/function): $$B(x,y)=\Gamma(x)\Gamma(y)/\Gamma(x+y)\tag{1}$$ as
$$\frac{1}{B(x,y)}=\frac{(x+y-1)}{\pi} \int_{0}^{\pi/2}
\cos[(x-y)t]~\cos^{x+y-1}t ~dt~ \mbox{[GR, p. 959]}.\tag{2}$$
Let $$S_n=\sum_{k=0}^{2n} (-1)^k \frac{{4n \choose 2k}}{{2n \choose k}}. \tag{3}$$
We change the summand into Gamma function using $\Gamma(2z)=\frac{2^{2z-1}}{\sqrt{\pi}} \Gamma(z+1/2)\Gamma(z)$, we
get $$S_n=\sqrt{\pi} \sum_{k=0}^{2n} (-1)^k \frac{\Gamma(z)}{\Gamma(z-k) \Gamma(k+1/2)},~~ z=2n+1/2.$$
We can re-write $S_n$ using (1) as
$$ S_n=\sqrt{\pi} \frac{\Gamma(z)}{\Gamma(z+1/2)} \sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{(-1)^k}{B(z-k,k+1/2)}.$$
Then $$S_n= \frac{2^{2n+1}}{\sqrt{\pi} \Gamma(2n)} \int_{0}^{\pi/2} \sum_{k=0}^{n} (-1)^k \cos[(k-n)t] \cos^{2n-1} t ~dt.$$
Note that [GR, p. 37] 
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{2n} (-1)^k \cos [(k-n)t] =\sum_{m=-n}^{n} (-1)^{m+n} \cos 2m t= (-1)^n \left[1+2\sum_{m=1}^{n}(-1)^m \cos 2mt\right]=\frac{\cos(2n+1)t}{\cos t}.
$$ 
We obtain 
$$
S_n=\frac{2^{2n}\Gamma(2n+1/2)}{\sqrt{\pi}\Gamma(2n)} \int_{0}^{\pi/2}  \cos(2n+1)t ~ \cos^{2n-2}t ~dt.
$$
Using the value of this integral from [GR, p. 416], we can write
$$S_n=\frac{2^{2n}\Gamma(2n+1/2)}{\sqrt{\pi}\Gamma(2n)}\left(\frac{\pi} {2^{2n-1}(2n-1) B(2n+1/2,-1/2)}\right).$$
Finally by opening  $B(x,y)$ and using $\Gamma(-1/2)=-2 \sqrt{\pi},$ we get 
$$ S_n=\frac{1}{1-2n}.$$
This sum (3) can be checked to be correct and consistent but it came mostly by the Table! So the question is: Can one give an alternate proof of (3) by hand which is simpler, more direct and characteristic?

Comment: Surely you can feed it into something like [Gosper's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gosper%27s_algorithm).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> By using  [W-Z method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilf%E2%80%93Zeilberger_pair), we show a more general identity: for $n\geq 2$,
>   $$\sum_{k=0}^{n} (-1)^k \frac{\binom{2n}{2k}}{\binom{n}{k}}=\frac{1+(-1)^n}{2(1-n)}.$$

Let
$$F(n,k)= (-1)^k \frac{\binom{2n}{2k}}{\binom{n}{k}}(n-1).$$
Then for $k=0,1,\dots,n$,
$$F(n+1,k)-F(n,k)=G(n,k+1)-G(n,k)$$
with
$$G(n,k)=(-1)^k\frac{\binom{2n}{2k-2}}{\binom{n+1}{k}}(n+1).$$
Hence
$$\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^{n+1}F(n+1,k)-\sum_{k=0}^{n}F(n,k)&=F(n+1,n+1)+
\sum_{k=0}^{n}(G(n,k+1)-G(n,k))\\
&=F(n+1,n+1)+G(n,n+1)-G(n,0)\\
&=(-1)^{n+1}n+(-1)^n(n+1)-0\\
&=(-1)^n.
\end{align}.$$
Finally, for $n\geq 2$,
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n} (-1)^k \frac{\binom{2n}{2k}}{\binom{n}{k}}=\frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{k=0}^{n}F(n,k)=\frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{k=2}^{n}(-1)^{k-1}=\frac{1+(-1)^n}{2(1-n)}.$$

Comment: Wonderful solution !

Answer (score 1):

Define
$$\newcommand{\bbinom}[2]{\left(\!\left({#1\atop#2}\right)\!\right)}
\begin{align}
\bbinom{n}{k}
&=\frac{\binom{2n}{2k}}{\binom{n}{k}}\\
&=\frac{(2n-1)!!}{(2k-1)!!\,(2n-2k-1)!!}\tag1
\end{align}
$$
Similar to $n\binom{n-1}{k-1}=k\binom{n}{k}$, we have
$$
(2n-1)\bbinom{n-1}{k-1}=(2k-1)\bbinom{n}{k}\tag2
$$
and just as $\binom{n}{n-k}=\binom{n}{k}$,
$$
\bbinom{n}{n-k}=\bbinom{n}{k}\tag3
$$

---

Until stated otherwise, assume $n$ is even.

Substituting $k\mapsto n-k$ and applying $(3)$ gives
$$
\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k(n-2k)\bbinom{n}{k}=\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^{n-k}(2k-n)\bbinom{n}{k}\tag4
$$
Since $n$ is even, $(4)$ implies
$$
\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k(n-2k)\bbinom{n}{k}=0\tag5
$$

---

Substituting $k\mapsto n-k+1$ and applying $(3)$, we get
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n(-1)^k\bbinom{n-1}{k-1}=\sum_{k=1}^n(-1)^{n-k+1}\bbinom{n-1}{k-1}\tag6
$$
Since $n$ is even, $(6)$ implies
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n(-1)^k\bbinom{n-1}{k-1}=0\tag7
$$

---

Applying $(2)$ to $(7)$ yields
$$
\begin{align}
-1
&=-1+\overbrace{\sum_{k=1}^n(-1)^k(2n-1)\bbinom{n-1}{k-1}}^{(2n-1)\cdot0}\\
&=-1+\sum_{k=1}^n(-1)^k(2k-1)\bbinom{n}{k}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k(2k-1)\bbinom{n}{k}\tag8
\end{align}
$$
Adding $(5)$ to $(8)$ and dividing by $n-1$ gives
$$
\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k\bbinom{n}{k}=-\frac1{n-1}\tag9
$$

---

Lifting the assumption that $n$ is even, equations $(7)$ and $(9)$ give the result
$$
\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k\frac{\binom{2n}{2k}}{\binom{n}{k}}
=-\frac1{n-1}[2\mid n]\tag{10}
$$
where $[\cdots]$ are [Iverson Brackets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket).